# Python - Class Factory

Tags: python, factory, metaclass

I'm using classes to design network conversations, I have this code:

```
class Conversation(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, received=0, sent=0):
        self.sent = sent
        self.received = received

    def __str__(self):
        return "<Conversation: received=" + str(self.received) + " sent=" + str(self.sent) + " >"

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Conversation)

    @classmethod
    def filter(cls, pkt):
        return True

    @abstractmethod
    def is_sent(self, pkt):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def add(self, pkt):
        if self.is_sent(pkt):
            self.sent += 1
        else:
            self.received += 1

class IPConversation(Conversation):
    def __init__(self, a_ip, b_ip, received=0, sent=0):
        super(IPConversation, self).__init__(received, sent)
        self.a_ip = a_ip
        self.b_ip = b_ip

    def __str__(self):
        return "<IPConversation: " + self.a_ip + " >>> " + self.b_ip

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if super(IPConversation, self).__eq__(other):
            a = (self.a_ip, self.b_ip)
            b = (other.ip_a, other.ip_b)
            return a == b or a == b[::-1]
        return False

    @classmethod
    def filter(cls, pkt):
        return super(IPConversation, cls).filter(pkt) and 'IP' in pkt
    def is_sent(self, pkt):
        return self.a_ip == pkt['IP'].src
```

but then I thought about creating the IPv6 class, and it will be the same as the IP class but the only difference is the 'IPv6' in pkt in front of 'IP' in the **classmethod**. how can I do it with a metaclass?

Comment: Why not simply use `class IPv6Conversation(IPConversation): pass`?

Comment: because I need then I need TCP and UDP to inherit from IP and then I would be able to create a class with the metaclass

Comment: You want TCP and UDP to inherit from IP, with IP being either IPv4 or IPv6? Can't you just make the version an attribute of IP?

Comment: Hi. Using meta-programming such as abc and metaclass is arguably considered harmful, especially if you are designing a new system. You can use simple techniques, such as factory *function* which generates desired *objects* directly instead of class